# How to find asymptotics?

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics

The function $\Phi:(0,\infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is defined as follows. We put $\Phi(x):=1$ if $x \ge 1$. Let the function $\Phi$ satisfy $$\Phi(x)=\int_0^x \Phi\left(\frac t {1-t}\right) \frac {dt} t $$ if $x <1.$ What is the asymptotics of $\Phi(x)$ as $x\downarrow 0$?

Comment: Are there any additional continuity properties imposed on $\Phi$?

Comment: @ Raskolnikov: No.

Comment: What about the point $x=1$? Any multiple of a solution for the interval $[0,1[$ is also a valid solution, but if you fix some continuity property in $1$, the solution might be unique. Of course, that does not really matter for the asymptotics in $0$ I presume. Except it would fix an overall factor.

Comment: @ Raskolnikov: Why is any multiple of a solution for the interval [0,1[  a valid solution?

Comment: Just look at your formula. If $\Phi$ is a solution, then so is $2\Phi$.

Comment: @ Raskolnikov:  Put $x= 3/4 $. $\Phi(x)$ is fixed for $x\ge 1.$

Comment: No source, no motivation, no sign of independent effort. Voting to close.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson :That problem is an example of so called thauberian theorems. It is authored by [A .Vershik](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zbmath/search/?q=Vershik,%20A.). 
Its aim is to select candidates for postgraduate studies.

Comment: @user64494: so you're asking us to solve a problem which is supposed to select candidates for postgraduate studies for you? Aren't you supposed to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: @ tomasz : I'm PhD in math for years. However, I can't prove that. I don't also know a proof of this problem. You may see my other questions too.

Comment: should a taylor series near $ x=0 $ work ??

Comment: Great problem :)! Are you OK w/ partial results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Dickman function (references: [1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DickmanFunction.html), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function)). Asymptotic analysis is usually done in terms of the function $\rho(u)$ defined by $\rho(u) = \Phi(1/u)$. [Xuan](https://eudml.org/doc/165143) (equation 1.6) gives the estimate
$$\rho(u) = \exp \left( -u \log u - u \log \log u +u - \frac{u \log \log u}{\log u} +O\left( \frac{u}{\log u} \right) \right).$$
Xuan cites papers of Hua and de Bruijn, neither of which I have easy access to. Wikipedia states without citation that $\rho(n) < 1/n!$ is easy to prove.

I also remember a good discussion of this in Volume 2 of the *Art of Computer Programming*, by Donald Knuth.

Comment: @ David Speyer: I am grateful to you for your comprehensive answer which was sure unexpected for me. The interplay between asymptotical analysis and computer sciences is of great interest to me. Of course, I find it correct. However, I would like to delay its acccepting. There is a chance that somebody will submit a straightforward proof of the asymptotics.

Comment: I'd love to see one! I was a little frustrated that I couldn't find a reference with proofs.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I've access to the de Bruijn paper, should you want it. Also: respect for the contribution!

Comment: @ automaton: Could you pteresent that in SE? It would be kind of you.

Comment: It would, indeed... Let me download it & try to read it first; if I find the time, I'll present a digest of the asymptotics. Meanwhile, DS should get the bounty from *my* POV.

Comment: @ David Speyer: I accept your answer though the one is not comlete. I have not found the article by de Bruijn with the proof  in the Internet. A. Vershik proposed that as a theme for students' research in 1989. Because of this reason I think that the proof of the one-term asymptotics is not too hard. BTW, A. Vershik also asked whether $\Phi(x) \in C^\infty(0,1)$.

Comment: $\Phi$ is not $C^{\infty}$ on $(0,1)$. That would correspond to $\rho$ being $C^{\infty}$ on $(1, \infty)$. The function $\rho$ is analytic on $[n,n+1]$ for each integer $n$, but is only $C^{n-1}$ at $n$. At this point, you should probably start reading papers if you want to know more.

Comment: That can be downloaded from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/memgmma3hlurjfx/statya1.pdf?dl=0).

Comment: The article by de Bruijn can be downloaded from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fp7ekq3ph163kjv/1209_001.pdf?dl=0).