# Polynomial with certain property

Tags: polynomials

Does there exist a polynomial $P$ over the rationals  s.t. for every $k=1,2,\dots,2015$ the equation $P(x)=k$ has exactly $k$ different rational roots, dropping multiplicities of these?

Comment: To clarify, you mean that P(x)=1 has one solution, while P(x)=2 has two solutions, and so on?

Comment: @ Alfred Verger : Yes. The roots must be rational and different, dropping multiplicities of these.

Comment: I think the downvote must be motivated by the downvoter. See [that](http://mathoverflow.net/users/65/ilya-nikokoshev).

Comment: It seems like there is another wave of downvoting going on. The last three questions I browsed -- all fine, IMO -- have had inexplicable downvotes in both the question and the answer.

Comment: @Ark, some people don't like questions that appear to have been copied from somewhere, with no indication of the source, and no indication of the slightest bit of effort on the part of the person posting the question, and those people might well vote down a question like this one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand that, and in some ways this question is on the fence, but given that the OP has sufficient reputation and is participating in comments, I'm willing to give it a pass on the "this problem is interesting and doesn't immediately appear to be a crowdsourced homework solution" test. The other questions I've seen, however, pass that test with flying colors. There seem to be a number of users with a perverse sense of unique ownership of what is/isn't good enough for this site, lately.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Please, think of [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433519/how-to-find-asymptotics).

Comment: It's hard to remember 64494. Maybe if you used your real name, I'd remember your posts from years ago.